# "Nonlinear" Gronwall-type inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, gronwall-type-inequality

Let $u: (0,\infty) \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Suppose that $\int_{\mathbb R} u(t,x) dx \ge 0$ (but not necessarily $u >0$). Let $A:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ with $A \ge 0$.  Let $\alpha \ge 0$.

Suppose that we know

> $$\frac{d}{dt} \alpha\int_{\mathbb R} u(t,x) dx + A(t) \le \int_{\mathbb R}u^2(t,x) dx.$$

Can we prove a **Gronwall-type inequality** that implies a bound like
$$\alpha\int_{\mathbb R} u(t,x) dx + \int_0^t A(t) dt \le e^t\alpha\int_{\mathbb R}u(0,x) dx$$
(or with something else related to $u(0,x)$ on the right-hand side).

This would be true if there was no square on the right-hand side by the classic Gronwall inequality, but I wonder if we can still say something in this case.

Comment: Would this not be the case where $\beta = u$, [as outlined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality)?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Nope: my objective is to have the right hand side depending on $u(0,x)$ not on $\int_0^tu(s,x) ds$